# Vue: Variable not safed, when other component is shown

Tags: vue.js

I have two components. One of it gives the value height to the other one, when "submit" is clicked. When "submit" is clicked the first component should be hidden and the second one visible.
It works so far, but it seems like height is not safed in the second component.

Thanks a lot!!

without the v-if it works perfect!

```
//ComponentOne
<template>
  <body>
    <div id="aside">
      <footer>
        <b-button  v-on:click="submit">Submit</b-button>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>

</template>

<script>
  import { EventBus } from '@/main.js'
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        submitp1: false,

        height: 5,
        width: 6,

      }
    },
    methods: {
      submit: function () {
        this.submitp1 = !(this.submitp1)
        EventBus.$emit('submitp1emit', this.submitp1)
 EventBus.$emit('1to2', this.height)
      }
    },
  }

</script>

//ComponentTwo
<template>
  <div >
    number <br />
   height:  {{height}}

</div>
</template>
<script>
  import { EventBus } from '@/main.js'
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        height: '',
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      const self = this
      EventBus.$on('1to2', function{ height) {
        self.height = height
      })
  }
  }

</script>

//main.js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ComponentOne v-if="submitp1 == false" />
    <ComponentTwo v-if="submitp1 == true" />

      </div>
</template>
<script>
  import { EventBus } from '@/main.js'
  import ComponentOne from '@/components/p1Comp/ComponentOne.vue'
  import ComponentTwo from '@/components/p1Comp/ComponentTwo.vue'



  export default {
    components: {
      ComponentOne,
ComponentTwo
}
    data: function () {
      return {
        submitp1: false
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      const self = this
      EventBus.$on('submitp1emit', function (submitp1emit) {
        self.submitp1 = submitp1emit
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: use `v-show` instead of `v-if`

Answer (score 0):

From the Vue documentation:

> v-if is “real” conditional rendering because it ensures that event
> listeners and child components inside the conditional block are
> properly destroyed and re-created during toggles.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show

The toggled component is simply not there. As already mentioned, you can use "v-show" instead.